# number of factorization of a square-free number

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

Is there a way to count the number of factorizations of a square-free number $n$? A square-free number is defined as an integer which is divisible by no perfect square other than $1$

Comment: How many "factorizations" does $30$ have?  Depending on what you mean, it is possible to give the number of factorizations as a function of the number of prime factors of $n$

Comment: $30$ has $5$ factorizations, which are $30, 5\times6, 15\times2, 10\times3, 5\times3\times2$

Comment: Then you want the [Bell numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) [OEIS A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110): $1,1,2, 5, 15, 52,\ldots$.  If $n=1$ or is prime then $1$ factorization, if $n$ is the product of two primes then $2$ factorizations, if $n$ is the product of three primes then $5$ factorizations, if $n$ is the product of four primes then $15$ factorizations, etc.

Comment: so if $n$ has $p$ prime factors, then the number of factorizations would be $B_{p}$ right?

Comment: Yes - for this definition of number of factorizations.  You might want to check that $210$ has $15$ to convince yourself

Comment: I think the term "factorization" usually refers to decompositions into _irreducible_ parts, which is certainly the way it is used in "unique factorization". The term (multiplicative) decomposition would therefore seem more appropriate in this question. By the way, the corresponding notion for the set of prime factors is called  a "set partition".